# Jquery nested foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

G'Day folks,
I have problems understanding foreach loops in Jquery especially the nested ones. I want to number every element and call them with an onclick method in a foreach- loop. I tried alot but none of the things I tried worked .:(

https://jsfiddle.net/sozf99a6/

```
HTML Structure
<div class='object'>
<div class='images'>
    <div class='bigImage'><img src=/></div>
    <div class='previewImage'><img src=/></div>
    <div class='bigImage'><img src=/></div>
    <div class='previewImage'><img src=/></div>
</div>
<div class='description'>blablabla</div>
<div class='description'>blablabla2</div>
<div class='description'>blablabla3</div>
```

```
Javascript
     //This function numbers every item to call it onclick
//each previewImage and description is assigned to one bigImage
$(function(){

  $('.object').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slider' + (i+1));

  $('.bigImage').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('product' + (i+1));

   $('.previewImage').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('navImage' + (i+1));

   $('.description').each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('slidetext' + (i+1));

});});
      /*
========^
    How it should works technically-
I)   
  $('.object').each(function(i){
     $(this).addClass('slider' + (i+1)).each(function(i){
      $('.bigImage').each(function(i){
              $(this).addClass('product' + (i+1));
              $('.previewImage').each(function(i){
              $(this).addClass('navImage' + (i+1));
              $('.description').each(function(i){
              $(this).addClass('slidetext' + (i+1));}
              });

 II)
    var i=0;
    $('.navImage'+('+i+')').click(function(i){
     $('.bigImage').hide();
     $('.product'+('+i+')').show();
     $('.description').hide();
     $('.slidetext'+('+i+')').show();  
   i++;
    });


*/
```

Thanks for helping me-

Comment: Your bracing is way off, thus you have Javascript syntax errors all over your code.  Start by going to the debug console and fix every error you see there.  Perhaps come back here after there are no more errors and all your code is actually running.  This is an important first step before you come here asking for help.  If you have a specific question about how to fix a particular error, you can ask about that here, but we aren't a syntax error fixing service so you should have done that step before coming here.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer - I did not intended to get Syntax correction and I do not want an error fixing service- I just want to know how to implement the faulty code I added in the comments. It does not need to be my code , I just wanted to introduce you to the problem fairly fast. I just want to get the concept of nested foreach loops as every other example was about list stuff which is not helping me at all. :)

Comment: You have 4 each loops which we don't know were should end so it's hard to say how your each loops are nested in order to help. You name all your each indexes with "i" so again we don't know what you want to achieve and where. Please check: http://jsfiddle.net/mka30pdL/ and update your questions accordingly of how your each loops are nested and what you need to achieve.